# Identify border-color in QTP

Tags: qtp

Which QTP property helps me identifying the border color of an element?

I want to to identify the color of the border inside the combo box when an invalid value is entered in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd6fA.jpg).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What technology are you testing against? What are you trying to achieve? It's difficult to answer your question if we don't understand the context.

Comment: I am testing the application which was built using 'WPF' technology .

Comment: I'm not familiar with WPF, perhaps you can try using a bitmap checkpoint